# Docker OpenJDK -Xmx or

Tags: java, docker, jvm

I am trying to get a service running in a container, but ran into the `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when the service in the container starts up (it does some memory intensive stuff).

I am trying to add the options for `-Xmx1024 -Xms1024`, but that didn't work.

I also attempted to use

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
```

as the [OpenJDK Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/openjdk/) documentation mentions, however when I run that, it fails with the following error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UnlockExperimentalVMOptions XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap'
```

The current `Dockerfile` that I am using looks like the following

```
FROM openjdk:8u131

...

...

CMD ["java","-XshowSettings:vm -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap","-jar", "target/my-jar.jar"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are specifying the arguments incorrectly.  This:

```
CMD ["java",
     "-XshowSettings:vm -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap",
     "-jar", "target/my-jar.jar"]
```

should be:

```
CMD ["java",
     "-XshowSettings:vm",
     "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions",
     "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap",
     "-jar", "target/my-jar.jar"]
```

When you use `CMD [ ... ]` you need to provide the arguments exactly as the shell would provide them.  This could also be why you couldn't get `-Xmx1024 -Xms1024` to work.

Answer (score 4):

OpenJDK 10 and up detect the cgroup limit automatically without any additional flags ([JDK-8146115](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8146115)). In addition they also let you specify the maximum heap size as fraction of that limit via the `MaxRAMPercentage` option ([JDK-8186248](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8186248)).